# Save webpage in webarchive (MHT) format controlled from embedded c or webpage

Tags: c, web-controls, mhtml

I have an embedded system (written in C) that is running a webserver, where there is about 50 webpages.
I would like to save all 50 pages in internet explorer mht format, but I don't want to browse through each of the websites and press "save as" in IE11.
Do you know if it is possible to control IE11 "save as" from the embedded system (c code) or from the webpage itself or any other ideas is also appreciated.
Regards Fenger

Comment: Yes it's possible.

Comment: Look up web page crawler